# Glimpse for .Net Core 3 and later?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, glimpse

Anyone used Glimpse for .net core 3.1 and later versions?

I couldn't find anything over web.

If not glimpse, can you suggest any similar tool for .Net Core 3.1 and later?

Thanks

Comment: You can try BenchmarkDotNet https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html

Comment: Do you want to use Glimpse with asp.net core3.1 or above?

Comment: @Chaodeng for 3.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use MiniProfiler as alternative.

https://miniprofiler.com/